# magento admin login through curl

Tags: php, magento

I want to post the magento admin username and password through curl once the login is successful should redirect to the magento admin dashboard.
How can i do it?
Basically magento login requires this information:

```
require_once ("magento\app\Mage.php" );
umask(0);

// Initialize Magento
Mage::app("default");

// You have two options here,
// "frontend" for frontend session or "adminhtml" for admin session
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "adminhtml"));
$session = Mage::getSingleton("admin/session");
```

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
$app = Mage::app('default');

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));

// supply username
$user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->loadByUsername('adminusername');

if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->useSecretKey()) {
  Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->renewSecretUrls();
}

$session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$session->setIsFirstVisit(true);
$session->setUser($user);
$session->setAcl(Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl());
Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_session_user_login_success',array('user'=>$user));

if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
  echo("logged in");
}
```

Comment: This is not working in magento 1.6.2 or 1.7.0.0 but working in 1.7.0.2 and less than 1.6 versions, is there any session change/dispatch event changed in the amdin login success?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of there may of been an ACL change possibly.