# Magento admin login with cURL

Tags: magento-1.6

I want to use user name and password to login admin panel with cURL to perform some actions.
Not like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973134/magento-admin-login-through-curl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$APIURL = "http://APIURL:port/API/login/";
$method = "POST";
$http = new Varien_Http_Client(APIURL."?username=".$login['username']."&password=".$login['password']);
$response = $http->request($method);
$body = $response->getBody();

try {
     $verifyUser = json_decode($body);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', $e);
}
```